# Tkinter ProgressBar and Os.Walk in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, progress-bar, os.walk

I have a working GUI with a wonky progress bar. My issues seems to be that I can't get the progress bar to step correctly based on the amount of items in the source directory. Any ideas?

```
def Progress(self):
    progress = Frame(self)
    progress.pack(fill=X)
    self.progressLine = ttk.Progressbar(progress, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=550, mode='determinate', maximum=100)
    self.progressLine.pack(pady=5)

def Scatter(self):
    self.t_start.delete('1.0', END)
    if Entry.get(self.sourceE) > 0 or Entry.get(self.destE) > 0:
        if not os.path.exists(Entry.get(self.sourceE)) or not os.path.exists(Entry.get(self.destE)):
            self.t_start.delete('1.0', END)
            self.t_start.insert(END, '*WARNING* Missing Source and/or Destination Folders')
            return

    self.t_start.delete('1.0', END)
    self.t_start.insert(END, "Counting Assets\n")
    self.totalFiles = len(list(os.walk(os.path.abspath(Entry.get(self.sourceE)))))
    self.stepFiles = (100/self.totalFiles)
    self.progressLine['value'] = self.stepFiles
    self.t_start.insert(END, "Process Started...\n")
    #self.progressLine.step(self.stepFiles)

    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(Entry.get(self.sourceE)):
        self.progressLine.step(self.stepFiles)
        for file in files:
            if not file.startswith('.'):
                subFolder = os.path.join(Entry.get(self.destE), file[:1], file[:2], file [:3], file [:4])
                checkFile = os.path.join(subFolder, file)
                if not os.path.isdir(subFolder):
                    os.makedirs(subFolder)
                if not os.path.exists(checkFile):
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), subFolder)
                else:
                    global fname, fextension
                    fname, fextension = os.path.splitext(file)
                    ii = 1
                    while True:
                        new_pname = os.path.join(subFolder, fname + "_" + str(ii) + fextension)
                        new_name = fname + "_" + str(ii) + fextension
                        if not os.path.exists(new_pname):
                            shutil.copy(checkFile, new_pname)
                            change_files = "From: " + file + " to: " + new_name + "\n"
                            self.t_start.insert(END, change_files)
                            if self.CheckVar.get() == 1:
                                delfile = os.path.join(root, file)
                                delete_files = "Deleted Original: " + file + "\n"
                                self.t_start.insert(END, delete_files)
                                os.remove(delfile)
                            break
                        ii += 1
            self.progressLine.update_idletasks()
    self.t_start.insert(END, "Process Complete")
    self.progressLine.update_idletasks()
```

Everything works, my only issue is the "stepFiles" variable. How would I go about making this more accurate then what I have already have?

Perhaps it is how I am calculating stepFiles? I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do division in Python with 2 ints you are going to get back an int (whole number).  So for example if you had 27 files:

```
>>> 100 / 27
3
```

Now we can see there's a huge problem here, since  `3 * 27 == 81`.  So if we step by 3 for 27 files you're only going to end with an 81% full progress bar.

You can fix this by feeding one float into your division for a more accurate result:

```
>>> 100.00 / 27
3.7037037037037037
```

--

Another way to fix this would be to set the `maximum` of your progressbar to `self.totalFiles` (after you calculate it of course) and then step by `1` for each file.

Comment: I removed maximum=100 from self.progressLine, took out self.stepFiles=(100/self.totalFiles), and set self.progressLine["maximum"] = self.totalFiles. But while the code runs, the progress bar still seems to max out and restart over-and-over again. - I feel like I am calling step too often?

Comment: All you needed to change was `self.stepFiles` to `self.stepFiles = (100.00/self.totalFiles)`

Comment: If you went that 2nd route then you needed to also change to `self.progressLine.step(1)`

Comment: I had to rejig some of my code to get it to step correctly but this did the trick!